# Router intrusion messages in activity log. What does it mean?

Tags: networking, wireless-router, firewall, adsl-router, security-warning

Today I decided to check my router security logs cuz I've had connectivity issues and I noticed something unusual and new to me, I noticed this line

> Intrusion -> SRC=190.71.82.227 DST=xx.xx.xxx.xx LEN=60 TOS=0x00
> PREC=0x00 TTL=42 ID=86 DFPROTO=TCP SPT=51065 DPT=45468 WINDOW=6

‭
when i checked the ip geolocation it was https://ipgeolocation.io/ip-location/190.71.82.227

what is this? I live in Egypt and got this intrusion from Colombia, and it's not the only one. I found multiple lines starting with Intrusion-> and each ipaddress gives a different location.

How can I deal with this cuz this got me paranoid

Comment: Have a look at https://security.stackexchange.com/q/191433/278877

Answer (score 1):

People from outside are always knocking at Router doorsteps. Very common activity.

> How can I deal with this

Set your router up to ignore this stuff (default settings on modern routers are normally adequate) and then ignore it.

It is not coming into your system (based on your post), and there is no one to complain to. Your ISP will not likely do anything.

So make sure your router is secure (read the router documentation) and ignore the stuff.